# Space as first character

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a little problem Im facing at the moment, the registration and login works just fine but there's one glitch in it. If you only enter space as Username (basically press space few times and thats it) it will actually let you register, and same goes for the login.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //kada kliknu dugme submit
        if(!empty($nameX) || !empty($passX))  { 
            if($XX == true) {
                if($passX == GetPlayerPassword($nameX)) {
                    echo "Dobrodosli nazad!";
                    header( 'Location: http://www.youtube.com/' );
                }
                else {
                    header( 'Location: ../main.php' );
                }
            }
            else {
                global $handler;
                echo "Novi account registrovan! Dobrodosli!";
                $tmpQuery = "INSERT INTO registrovani (Username, Password) VALUES ('".$nameX."','".$passX."')"; 
                mysqli_query($handler,$tmpQuery);
            }
        }
        else if(empty($nameX) || empty($passX)){
            header( 'Location: ../main.php' );
        }
    }
```

So basically I can just register by pressing space few times in order to avoid username and password entry.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Comment: Just so you know, absolutely nothing about this is "fine" and if anything this is the opposite of fine. There's so many problems here that you really need to re-think this from the ground up.

Comment: Im making this for fun, Im not making it to be secure or anything, Im just learning PHP so preety much this is code that wont be used by others or anything as such therefore I dont worry about SQL Injections or such.
Altho thank you for poiting me where should I go

Comment: "I dont worry about SQL Injections" is a lie, don't even start. If you're putting this on the internet, you're exposed to risks. If your friends use this service, you're putting them at risk. Doing it the right way is easier, not harder, and in addition to that you'll learn the *right way* instead of this mess of code that's completely unmaintainable and teaches you nothing other than bad habits you'll have to painfully un-learn later. If you want to learn, that's great. Just don't fall into the trap of thinking learning the right way doesn't matter.

Comment: As I said, I just started learning PHP, I barely put this code together, you cant expect of me to have 100% secure code after 2 days of learning PHP but as I said, thank you for letting me know, I really want to improve my code but at this point I just wanna put stuff together for myself, and of course I dont plan to put this on internet.

EDIT: If you could throw me some YT video on how to do it Id also appreciate since its way easier for me to learn that way

Comment: I get what you're saying but I'm trying to emphasize that the way you're approaching this is the wrong way to go and you're making life way, way harder than it needs to be. A framework will support you in your learning, it'll lead by example, and you can avoid twenty years of messy PHP history in the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, could you provide me with some sort of video also where I could learn more about this? And is there a way to test if Im protected at any point or not

Comment: In my second comment I posted a link to a bunch of frameworks. They've all got their pros and cons, none is necessarily the best, but if you had to pick one at random you would do alright with [Laravel](http://laravel.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [trim](http://php.net/trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces in the username before inserting the new record in the database.
You also probably want to add some code to reject registration in case the login the username is made only of spaces.

```
$nameX = trim($_POST['name']);
if ($nameX == '') {
   // registration rejected
}
else {
  // insert the record in the database
}
```

You should use `trim` when a user is logging in too.

Comment: Hmm interesting so Id just add up the $nameX = trim($nameX); after the $nameX = $_POST['name']; correct? Im sorry, Im quite new to PHP

Comment: Yes, or you may do it in a single line of code, as in my answer.